# munin / rrdtool how to create graph with Y axis has different down and up scales?

Tags: rrdtool, graph, scale

It is possible to tell MUMIN plugin draw graph with different up and down Y axis scales? I looked for this on Internet but found nothing. I read mumin docs, but this points to RRDtool docs. In last one I found nothing.

Answer (score 7):

RRDTool (as of version 1.4) does not allow you to have different scales on the Y-axis above and below.

What it does allow you to do is to create a secondary Y-axis with a scale shift argument.  Items are still plotted according to the primary Y axis, though, so you need to perform any necessary calculations yourself.  The necessary parameter is --right-axis.

http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph.en.html